# I want to add discount by click on custom button in Add-to-cart page. How to do this?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
function add_content(){
     
        if(isset($_POST['takeway'])) {
            // Call Recalculate function
            add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 30 );
        } 
    ?> 
    <form method="post"> 
        <input type="submit" name="takeway" value="Takeway"/> 
    </form>

<?php

}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'add_content');



// Recalculate Function       
function woocommerce_after_calculate_totals( $cart ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_subtotal();
    $discount = 40/100;
    $cart->total = $subtotal*$discount;

}
```

cart->get_subtotal();
    $discount = 40/100;
    $cart->total = $subtotal*$discount;

}
```

```
your text
```

I want to add discont by clicking on HTML button in woocommerce cart page. But by using button it not working, without button it's working fine.

Comment: On button click, you'll have to same some kind of button click flag on cookies/session/database then you'll have to check that value in your discount apply function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. This will help you out for your next step process

Example working code:

```
function add_content(){  
    ?> 
    <form method="post"> 
        <input type="submit" name="takeway" value="Takeway"/> 
    </form>

<?php

}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'add_content');


add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'elex_discount_price' ); 

function elex_discount_price($cart) 
{ 
global $woocommerce; //Set the price for user role. 

if(isset($_POST['takeway'])) {
$discount_price = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal * 40 / 100;  

$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Discounted Price', -$discount_price, true, 'standard' ); 
}
}
```

For more detail information please refer to below link:
http://thewebfosters.com/adding-custom-data-woocommerce-order-add-cart/

Comment: thank you so much for your kind replay, it is updating cart total, subtotal and discount and not changing total, subtotal and discount in checkout order details. how to do that??

Comment: You can follow the steps from this link: http://thewebfosters.com/adding-custom-data-woocommerce-order-add-cart/